# trouble filtering through multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model

summary:
Basically, I want the user to input the title of a parter to filter a list of distributions on. One distribution has one profile, but one partner has many distributions. So, if someone were to put one partner title into the search form. That would correspond to multiple distribution ids (by way of multiple matching_profile ids).

I should describe the three models in question:

```
distribution:
  belongs_to :matching_profile, :counter_cache => true

matching_profile:
  belongs_to :partner

partner:
  has_many :matching_profiles
```

I basically need to access partner.title through the distribution model.

i can do it in SQL:
`select d.* from distributions d join matching_profiles m on d.matching_profile_id = m.id join partners p on m.partner_id = p.id where p.title in ( 'TITLE' )`
/summary

UPDATE:
here, effectively, is what I'd like to do. There are some gaps missing though...Please help!

in my controller i have:

```
@search = Distribution.workflow.order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).search(params[:traits_searchable_search])
```

in the view I have:

```
<%= form_for @search, :url => url_for(:controller => params[:controller], :action => params[:action]), :html => {id => "distribution_workflow",:method => :get} do |f| %>

 <div class="form-block mrl mbm mtm">
      <%= f.label 'matching_profile.partner.title_equal', "Partner" %>
      <%= f.select @search.where('matching_profile_id in (select id from matching_profiles where partner_id in (select id from partners where title in (?)))'), Partner.select(:title), :include_blank => " " %>
    </div>
```

the f.select part is what is incorrect but i think the IDEA of what I'm trying to do is captured here. I just don't know HOW to do it.
/update

I'm presenting a report in a web page and i need to allow the user to filter out which rows are available based on the title of a partner. The title of the partner however is not in the model that I've created the form for. The form is for the distribution model, which has a reference to matching_profile, which has a reference to partner. the partners table is the one that contains the title that I'd like to filter on.

Currently, I tried to accomplish this by adding another `search_scope`

```
search_scopes :equal   => [:status, 'matching_profile.partner.title'] #obviously very wrong
```

update: I also tried this:

```
search_scopes :equal   => [:status, 'distributions.matching_profile.partner.title']
```

this doesn't give me an error, but doesn't filter either. a step in the right direction? /update

but i'm getting an error because I can't seem to "hop" two tables to get to the title. I'm seeing this in the error message:

```
AND (matching_profile.partner.title = 'PARTNER_TITLE')
```

of course, this is wrong because there's no matching_profile field, only matching_profile_id.

I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have any [`:through`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html) relationships in your Models?

Comment: no `:through`s. just `:belongs_to`

Comment: did a little research on the `:through` keyword - looks like i need something that goes the other direction, i.e. a shortcut on `:belongs_to` instead of `:has_many`

Comment: Thanks for the more complete description of the models; hopefully that will be enough for someone to suggest the cleanest approach forward. I'd like to suggest moving the logic out of your view and into your controller, but that won't actually help in solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, what I ended up having to do is adding a new option in my searchable trait to allow for an :in search. From there I had to do some re-jiggering to make the serialization happy, but it was relatively straightforward once i realized i could extend the searchable trait. I added this:

```
    unless options[:in].blank?
      [options[:in]].flatten.each do |field|
        scope "#{field}_in", lambda {|value| Rails.logger.info('value: ' + value.to_s)
        vals = []
        value.each do |v|
          vals << v.split(',') unless v.blank? || v.nil?
        end
        {:conditions => ["#{table_names(field)}#{field} in (?)", vals.flatten ]}}
      end
    end
```

then in my distribution model I added:

```
search_scopes :in    => [:matching_profile_id]
```

and finally in my view I could do this:

```
<div class="form-block mrl mbm mtm">
  <%= f.label :matching_profile_id_in, "Partner" %>
  <%= f.select :matching_profile_id_in, Partner.all.map { |p| [p.title, MatchingProfile.find_all_by_partner_id(p.id).map {|m| m.id}.join(',')]}, {:include_blank => " "}, {:multiple => true}  %>
</div>
```

and the controller magically stays the same.